# Making a mock UNIX shell

Tags: c, shell, unix

Hello I am trying to make a mock shell using execv and fork, but I'm running into a couple of issues in the functions I have made. Pretty much the program is supposed to run like a shell, allowing simple commands in the foreground and the background.
So now I fixed most of the errors that were mentioned and now I am left with two errors on the ptr[args] = NULL; where it says assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast and the second error is the strcat where it says invalid type of argument of 'unary *'(have 'int') Please help I do not know how to fix them.

```
int argCount(char *numofArgs){
        int count = 0, index = 0;

        for(count; numofArgs[index] != '\0'; index++){
                if(numofArgs[index] == ' ' || (numofArgs[index] ==  ' ' && numofArgs[index+1] == ' ')){
                        count++;
                }
        }
        count++;
}

 void parse(char *str, int numOfArgs, char* args){
        char *token1;
        const char s[1] = " ";
        //gets first token
        token1 =  strtok(str, s);
        while(token1 != NULL){
                token1 = strtok(NULL, s);
        }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv[]){
        //holds commands
        char hcomm[512];
        char *path = "/bin", *ptrarr;
        char dummy[512];
        int args, exe;
        while(1){
                printf("dummy&gt");
                fgets(hcomm, 512, stdin);
                int pid = fork();
                        if(pid != 0){
                                wait(NULL);
                        }
                        else{
                                //child if pid = 0
                                //args = counts number of args
                                args = argCount(hcomm);
                                //array of pointers for args to passed into
                                ptrarr[args + 1];

                                //need to parse the input and arguments
                                parse(hcomm, args, ptrarr);
                                //set last pointer to NULL
                                ptrarr[args] = NULL;
                                strcpy(dummy, path);
                                //concat dummy to /bin/
                                strcat(dummy, *ptrarr[0]);
                                //pass to exe
                                exe = execv(dummy, ptrarr);
                        }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Bash" is a large (almost) superset of POSIX sh. This does not try to be bash. It doesn't even try to be POSIX sh. It doesn't even try to be 1970s-era Bourne. Please don't tag something "bash" if it isn't related to bash; a better tag for this would just be "shell", inasmuch as it's a shell question at all.

Comment: Also -- as a general rule for _any_ post on StackOverflow, please try to reduce to the smallest possible chunk of code which will reproduce a given problem before posting. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: My bad, I'm pretty new to Stack so I'm still getting used to it. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of warnings/errors there and I don't quite feel like addressing them all. That's because even just one error illustrates a deep misunderstanding of what's going on. So I'm going to just talk about the first warning:

> dummyshell.c:10: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer

I presume this refers to:

```
strcmp(numofArgs[index], " ") = 0
```

First of all, `strcmp` expects a string. By that what I mean is a pointer to an array of chars. You passing it `numofArgs[index]` causes it to treat that value as a pointer. It will then try to process a string pointed to by that pointer. I highly doubt that that memory address actually contains a string. For example, if `numofArgs[index]` happens to contain the character `'A'`, it translates to the memory address 0x00000041 (because the ASCII value of `'A'` is 0x41). If by coincidence that address contains a string, you're safe. But even then, I don't think it will do what you think it should do.

Second, `strcmp` process a string until it finds a NUL terminator (0x00). Thus, if the character `'A'` from the input happens to point to a region of memory that happens to be a space character, it may still not compare correctly to the space character you provide. For example, say the input character is `A`. As discussed, this means your're passing a string located at 0x00000041 to `strcmp`. Say for example that the string at that location happens to be `" ok"` (space, o, k). In this situation, strcmp will still not return 0 because it's comparing `" ok"` with `" "`.

In short, `strcmp` is for comparing strings (NUL terminated array of char). It's not for comparing characters.

What you probably meant instead is this:

```
if(numofArgs[index] == ' ' || (numofArgs[index] == ' ' && numofArgs[index+1] == ' ')){
    count++;
}
```

That logic is still quite messy and can be improved but at least it is correct.

Comment: Alright thank you. I actually had similar to that before, but I changed it to the strcmp() which I know now to be wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

- Don't use the assignment operator `=` instead of test for equality `==`.
- You declare several variables (`numofArgs`, `ptrarr`) as `const char*` or `char*`. That's fine if you want each of them to point to one string. If you would like to have an array of strings (and it looks like that's what you meant), use something like `const char*[32]` (when initializing) or `const char**` (in a parameter list) instead.
- Some of your statements do nothing: `ptrarr[args + 1];`

Comment: I think I fixed most of the things you mentioned. Thanks!